# Do not understand NLTK Regex Parsing Format

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I dont understand how does NLTK Regex Parsing Syntax works. 
Kindly see below.

```
parser = RegexpParser('''
    NP: {<DT>? <JJ>* <NN>*} # NP
    P: {<IN>}           # Preposition
    V: {<V.*>}          # Verb
    PP: {<P> <NP>}      # PP -> P NP
    VP: {<V> <NP|PP>*}  # VP -> V (NP|PP)*
    ''')
```

What does `<DT>?` or * mean. 
Whats the difference between `<V>.*` and `<V.*>`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DT is a determiner like a,the ,...

Verb participle defintion - A participle (glossing abbreviation PTCP) is a form of a verb that is used in a sentence to modify a noun, noun phrase, verb, or verb phrase, and plays a role similar to an adjective or adverb. ... It is one of the types of nonfinite verb forms.

```
<V>.* is for verb participle   example : drawn sword (drawn is vp)
<V.*> is a verb                example :going , go
```

You can find more about them here :
https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

What does * mean ?  It's the same * that's used in regular expressions. * denotes any set of characters (Ofcourse the set of characters that constitute the * should make sense upon combination)

Let's go into some examples -

```
<V.*> A verb followed by anything in the same run like go(ing) mov(ing)
```

Comment: Thanks Satyadev. But what if for example: I want to match a verb plus any number of words in between and ending with a noun. How to do that?
Is it `<V.*> .* <NN.*>`